# Where did Star-Lord get the troll doll?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

At the end of the Guardians of the Galaxy movie,

> Star-Lord tricks Yondu by giving him a troll doll instead of an infinity stone.

We know that when Peter Quill (a.k.a. Star-Lord) was abducted he had on him the cassette player (with the Awesome Mix), as well as the gift his mother had given him.  I think that we are to assume that since troll dolls were all the rage in the early eighties that the troll doll was Peter's from childhood and that it also came with him during the abduction.

Here is my question: do we actually see Peter in possession of the troll doll at any point in the movie prior to the end, or are we just supposed to assume it was on his person during his abduction?

Comment: he has that bag with him when he gets abducted, and then you see the troll a couple times in his ship before the ending scene.

Comment: I was more concerned about the in-dash cassette player!

Comment: @JeffPaquette Haha, that's true!  I just assumed he built that, but it did have quite a retro feel.

Comment: It *is* curious that he took it with him off the ship though. I felt like it was part of his little Earth-shrine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When young Peter Quill is abducted from Earth, he is wearing not only the cassette player but also a backpack. Although we never see the contents of the backpack, it is safe to assume that the troll doll and other objects were located in the backpack. Most boys his age in 1988 would have also had a couple of slap-straps in there and at least one Transformer or G.I.Joe figure as well.

UPDATE: As mentioned by Himarm, there are a couple of scenes in the film where you see a wide shot of Peter's "Earth Shrine" onboard the Milano, and it does indeed have numerous little "artifacts" surrounding it (including at least one troll doll). Most of these items were likely in Quill's backpack at the time of his abduction.

I couldn't find a clear shot of the backpack, but in the image below you can clearly see the strap on his left shoulder:

[image]

Comment: Yondu also has a lineup of talismanic gewgaws on his ship - he mentions them when he's threatening The Broker, and takes a blue crystal gewgaw in that scene.  He's later shown lovingly placing that on his armrest along with a handful of other things before the battle over Nova Prime.  What I want to know is, do we see the troll doll in that scene?  Because they were that sort of things.  If you can flip through scenes, look for that one :)

Comment: They show Yondu putting the troll doll on his console after the battle of Nova Prime.

Comment: I just checked; the troll is _not_ one of the gewgaws on Yondu's armrest _before_ the battle.  Sorry, false alarm :)

Comment: In the scene, where Peter flees from the Kree after obtaining the Orb, the troll is floating in his cockpit. And it's also there standing right beside the tape deck on his ship.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/u6vuM.png

Answer (score 11):

As @souichiro [mentioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66130/where-did-star-lord-get-the-troll-doll#comment138062_66138), the troll doll is in at least one earlier scene.

For example, after Peter first obtains the orb, it can be seen by his tape deck.

[image: Tape Deck]